# No value given for one or more required parameters in select query

Tags: sql, vb.net

Something is wrong with the select query. How can I add the right thing after (where)?

```
Private Sub sal_b1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sal_b1.Click
    If ComboBox3.Text <> "" Then
        Try
            Me.Refresh()
            con.Open()
            ds = New DataSet
            tables = ds.Tables
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select inv_sall2.outdate, inv_sall2.custName, inv_sall2.ac, inv_sall2.subtotal, inv_sall2.taf, inv_sall.itemName, inv_sall.quntity, inv_sall.itemPrice, inv_sall.Tottal From inv_sall INNER Join inv_sall2 On inv_sall.no = inv_sall2.invoceno WHERE (((inv_sall2.invoceno)= '" & ComboBox3.Text & "'));", con)
            da.Fill(Form2.hazemDataSet, "datatable1")
            Form2.Show()
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        MsgBox("please select the invoice number")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)

Comment: Connections should be disposed in addition to closed.

Comment: Why do create a new DataSet and a variable to hold the Tables collection of that new DataSet and never use either of them?

Comment: If you are using a DataAdapter it will open and close the connection for you. I any case don't open the connection several lines before it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change it like:

```
WHERE inv_sall2.invoceno = " & ComboBox3.Text & ";", con)
```